Use specific property in object validation
I have the following code:
A resource:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Resource {

  private final Service service;

  @POST
  @Path("/{id}/create")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response create(@PathParam("id") int id, @Valid @NotNull final Dto dto) {
    return Response.ok(service.save(id, dto)).build();
  }

A Dto:
@Getter
@Future
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Dto {

  @NotNull
  private LocalDateTime start;

  @NotNull
  private LocalDateTime end;

}

And the Validator:
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FutureValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Future, Dto> {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(final Dto dto, final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return dto.getStart().isAfter(LocalDateTime.now()) && dto.getEnd().isAfter(dto.getStart());
  }

}

The problem is that I need to compare start with a LocalDateTime in a custom time zone, which in addition depends of an external property retrieved from a call in the service (Service#getTimeZone(int id)). How can I add such property to the validator dynamically?

Sounds like the validation should happen in the service.

@forty-two I agree, probably that's what I'll do

You could hook yourself to spring Locale management. It handles TimeZone as well. You would need to implement your own LocaleContextResolver that that depends on your property and Service#getTimeZone(id). The only assumption is that you could retrieve this id from the request (header, cookie, auth context, etc...)
Something like
@Component(DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
public class MyLocaleResolver extends AbstractLocaleContextResolver {

    @Autowired private Service service;

    @Override
    public LocaleContext resolveLocaleContext(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String id = request.getHeader("x-something"); // header, cookie, or SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy().getContext() or anything.

        TimeZone timeZone = service.getTimeZone(id);
        return new TimeZoneAwareLocaleContext() {
            @Override
            @Nullable
            public Locale getLocale() {
                return getDefaultLocale(); // Or take the opportunity to set the proper one
            }
            @Override
            public TimeZone getTimeZone() {
                return timeZone;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocaleContext(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, LocaleContext localeContext) {
        // you probably don't need this
    }
}

Once the Locale resolver is properly configured, inside FutureValidator you could either

get it from threadLocal static context ((TimeZoneAwareLocaleContext) LocaleContextHolder.getLocaleContext()).getTimeZone()
get it from the request (you could inject it) RequestContextUtils.getTimeZone(request)
inject directly @Autowired TimeZone timeZone (not exactly sure, it works for Locale, to be tested with TimeZone instance)


Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I can't retrieve the id from the request

If its possible to modify the Dto to accept id(lets say timeZoneId) as a payload field instead of PathParam, we can inject Service in the validator to get the timeZone Service#getTimeZone(int id). Then we can get current datetime for that zone - using ZoneId
    ZoneId zoneId = service.getTimeZone(dto.getTimeZoneId());
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(zoneId);


I thought about this, but I'd like to know if there's a solution without modifying Dto

You could create a custom annotation validated by Custom Validator(FutureValidator). And from the controller remove @Valid and instead explictly call your validator after setting zoneId.
Refer a similar blog
https://github.com/hellozin/TIL/blob/master/box/BlogPost/enum-validator.md

I also thought about that but in that case I think it is much simpler to validate that directly in the service

Yes! Sometimes we need to prefer simplicity for the sake of maintainability.
